# How i can use Cryptography library to encryption files in python

Tags: python-2.7, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt PDF file using `crypto` and everything works well but I need to use another library like `Cryptography` https://github.com/pyca/cryptography .

How I can use `Cryptography` library to encrypt and decrypt files like PDF file because I search a lot and I can't find one example of how I can use `Cryptography` with files.

Any example may help.

Comment: if module can encrypt only string then read file into memory, use module and save encrypted data to file.

Comment: do you still seek an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question Cryptography's documentation could potentially help you with this. I used the library to encrypt text files, python files, i not sure about pdf's though. But the doc's were helpful.  https://cryptography.io/en/latest/

Plus this website also helped me out as well.

https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/encrypt-decrypt-files-symmetric-python

It implements the Fernet key type encryption which is symmetric encryption.

There is asymmetric encryption (I believe this type uses public and private keys) you can as far i know encrypt strings with this type of encryption. As far as encrypting files with this type of encryption i am not sure about that as i have not done any research on that my self lol!

I was messing around with some of the functions in this library and found some useful things in it. Hope this helps.

**p.s. Stay away from the hazmat section of this library. ONLY use this if you really know what your doing in terms of cryptography!**